# Remove empty or content-specified tables

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have **multiple** complex tables being uploaded in my present HTML page. The tables in sources are automatically generated by other software, so these empty tables are act as placeholders.

```
<table width="89%" height="1%" cellpadding="0" border="0px" align="center" style="">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"><font face="Arial">&nbsp;</font></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The content of emptly tables could be empty, single ESC like "&nbsp" or single punctuation like "-"

So what I have to do is to

-Detect if the table **satisfies the above conditions**.

-**REMOVE** the tables.

Thanks!

Comment: Get all tables with `document.getElementsByTagName("table");`, iterate through the collection, check the element's `.textContent` property, and compare the value to whether or not you think it's "empty"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by the clearing the table, but to remove the content from a `<td>` you can use either jquery.

```
for each (elem in $('td')) {
    elem.innerHTML = ""
}
```

This remove the content from all the tables in the document.

In Javacript, you can

```
for each (elem in document.getElementsByTagName('td')) {
    elem.innerHTML = ""
}
```

If you want to remove the entire table, then

```
$('table').remove()
```

Warning this removes all the tables though.

If you want specific tables to be removed, then you can use their css selectors in `$(selector)` to remove those specific table.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for replying. I edited my question. I have multiple tables uploaded, and what i mean is to remove the whole table which satisfies the condition above.

Comment: Edited the answer to satisfy your condition.

Comment: Thanks again. Probably i didn't have a clear statement and i apologize for that so i edit again. My core problem is how to check the content of a table if it is empty or carry the specified content. If yes, then remove the table.

Comment: To check the tables content, you can do `$('#table1').textContent` to get the text within a table. Hope that makes sense.